# Web site to Web App: aspx.cs can't see controls in .aspx

Tags: asp.net, vs-web-site-project, vs-web-application-project

I am trying to convert a web site project to a web app and I'm running into some issues where the .aspx.cs files can't see any controls in the .aspx. I've tried deleting the .designer.cs files and converting to a web app again but that hasn't fixed my problems. If I change the namespace of the .designer.cs files to 'SoftwareCheckout,' (the same namespace as my .aspx.cs) the .aspx.cs  can see the controls in the .aspx fine, but since the .designer.cs is auto-generated, I will loose any changes to it as soon as it's regenerated. This leads me to believe it is a problem with my namespaces but I'm not 100% sure.

Here is the top line of my .aspx called StuCheckout.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" Inherits="StuCheckout" Codebehind="StuCheckout.aspx.cs" %>
```

Here's the first couple lines of my .aspx.cs called StuCheckout.aspx.cs (lblUser and lblTime can't be accessed for example)

```
namespace SoftwareCheckout
{
    public partial class StuCheckout : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                lblUser.Text = CurrentUser.getUsername();
                lblTime.Text = CurrentUser.getDate();
                setLocalRestrictions();
                if (!(lblErrorText.Text == String.Empty))
                    lblErrorText.Visible = true;
```

My .designer.cs looks like this:

```
 //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated. 
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------



public partial class StuCheckout {

/// <summary>
/// Head1 control.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Auto-generated field.
/// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
/// </remarks>
protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlHead Head1;
```

Has anyone else ran into this issue? I'm running out of ideas here, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the namespace to the Inherits and Class declarations on your front-side (.aspx) pages; the @Page directive has an Inherits or Class attribute you can use.
See "Additional Conversion Options" section here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476(v=vs.100).aspx